# How to add glow effect on the skin of a model?

Tags: photo-editing, image-editing, lighting-effects

I'm working on the post production on a few dress photos, still, the designer of the dresses is not satisfied with the outcome, and wants the second picture to look like the first in terms of skin color, background, and structure.

So please help me guys:

1. How to achieve the slowly like effect on the skin?
2. How to add more structure to the photo so it won't look that flat?

How I want it to look (sample):
[image: How I want it to look (sample)]

How it looks now:
[image: How it looks]

Answer (score 1):

So I think you're adding the dress to the model post photographing?

The front doesn't look too bad to me but the back looks like you've added drop shadow? Also I think you've added way too much vibrancy so it's standing off the model too much. If you got some blacks in the dress you'd see the shape a lot better.

I also, personally might be inclined to give a bit of waist line. The rear view is quite straight.

Finally on the front view you have her on a very flat background. Perhaps if you tried to add a floor kind of aspect to it the whole thing wouldn't look flat.

Hope that helps a bit. The drop shadow on the back of the model though is something that's really not working (as with all design though it's just an opinion)

Comment: actually to add to that it might help to warp / puppet warp (this might work better) some of the upper dots, decorative bits to wrap around the shoulder blades a bit

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to 2nd photo:

The backround seems like it is tried to make cleaner by eraser tool in PS. It still has some remnants here an there. My modifications:

- clipped off the backround (+shaved out a bunch of crap that was caused)
- put a thin grey gradient as a new background
- tried to puppet warp the right side of the body (this really needs some talent and expertice, more than I have)
- reduced the red color to less offending saturation level to be able to add light wihout masking
- shifted the skintone towards typical North European (=narrow band Hue shift from orange to red + less saturation + more luminosity)
- added a bit of light;

Note: The hands had originally nearly the wanted color. Thus mods to them were reduced by layer mask.

No plugins are used, only native PS controls

[image]
Offtopic: This photo has an inherent problem: Hetero males subliminally may not like the dress at all, they probably want to take it off (the dress is fine, the reason must be elsewhere). More gallant, proud and valiant pose or simply more distant view could help to keep the thoughts in shape. Important dress details can be covered by closeups.